# Azure Logic App Standard - service bus trigger never triggered

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have a stateful workflow deployed in the new Logic App Standard hosting model.
The trigger is the Service Bus Receive Messages from a Queue.
After the deployment in Azure, I can see that the trigger is never triggered, even if I have messages active in the queue.
I tried to disable the workflow and re-enable it, but still the same issue.

Comment: Could you please give a screenshot of your azure logic app?

Comment: I have additional information to share: I can see that the Workflow URL displayed in the Overview page of the Logic App is empty.
And when I look into the Activity Log, I can see that there is an error while trying to call the ListCallBackUrl operation with a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found that this is a bug and to fix it I need to change manually the value assigned to the App Settings AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__version.
Instead of the default value, I need to force the value to "[1.1.16, 2.0.0)".

Based on this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/406403/logic-apps-preview-service-bus-receive-stopped-wor.html